# What does "placed calls" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've met the following expression: "placed and received calls". What exactly does "placed calls" mean? Is it a exact synonym for "outgoing calls"?

Comment: *Placed* calls just means calls made (and connected). An unanswered call would not be a *placed* call.

Comment: "To place a call" is roughly synonymous with "to telephone".  It feels *slightly* old-fashioned, like something that was used back when you needed an operator to help you telephone someone.

Comment: @Mick - My phone keeps a log of placed calls, and any outgoing call gets put in there, whether the other person answers or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mick and @Andrew have said, *to place (a call)* is to make a telephone call that the recipient answers. See this definition (from Oxford Dictionaries):

> [**place**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/place)
>   *Verb [with object]*
>   **2.3.** Order or obtain a connection for (a telephone call) through an
>   operator
>   *"she placed a call to her husband to break the news"*

As Mick and Andrew rightly said, and as can be seen from the definition, it's an old-fashioned term. Telephone operators are almost entirely a thing of the past, too.

More modern verbs for making a telephone call are [*to phone*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phone) and [*to call*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call). I don't know whether there's a more modern term that retains the element of the call being successful, but there is a slightly different word that could be used in combination:

> [**connect**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/connect)
>   *Verb*
>   **1.3.** Put (someone) into contact by telephone:
>   *"I was quickly connected to the police"*

You could then say, explicitly showing both the call being made and being answered, that:

> She took out her phone and **called** information, and was soon **connected**
>   to the power company, who put her on hold for 45 minutes.

*To connect* does imply some sort of operator being present, though it could be a human operator or an automated system.